# SQLite query Total

Tags: sql, sqlite, sum, price

I've got issue how to make a query total SUM from a table when need multiple 2 columns and then calculate a total sum of all rows.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BU5VO.png)

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some [sample data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 0):

```
select column1,sum(column2*column3)as col from yourtable
group by column1
union all
select '' column1,sum(column2*column3)as col from yourtable
order by column1
```

Comment: I appreciate a reply.

but I've got a result 5 instead of 46 

I using when:

    ID|  Price | Quantity
    
    1    6.00        3
    2    7.00        4


Example how it's looks my table
[Table example][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zKk0.png

Answer (score 0):

It is just a simple sum over `Quantity*Price`:

```
SELECT SUM(Quantity*Price) AS result FROM tablename
```

You don't seem to need any grouping.